# Streaming Transformations for XML (STX)

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, streaming

I am using a stylesheet to transform the following XML document using STX. But, everything after Kite in the comments element is getting ignored while parsing.

How can I access the lines within the BR tags using STX Stylesheet?
I need all the lines except the BR tags in the transformed file in the comments column.

[XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VAFas.png)

I tried using my stylesheet and it's skipping everything after Kite is being ignored.

Comment: IMHO, XSLT 3.0 supersedes *Streaming Transformations for XML (STX)*, and it has streaming capabilities.

Comment: I can only use STX version 1. Is it not possible to do using STX v1?

Comment: Please post any XML input as code samples, not as images.

Comment: If the answer solved your problem consider to accept it so that the question is being marked as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It seems easy to e.g. skip any `BR` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<stx:transform xmlns:stx="http://stx.sourceforge.net/2002/ns" version="1.0"
               pass-through="all">

  <stx:template match="BR"/>

</stx:transform>
```